# Encapsulating an external data source in a repository pattern

Tags: rest, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories, ddd-service

I am creating the high level design for a new service. The complexity of the service warrants using DDD (I think). So I did the conventional thing and created domain services, aggregates, repositories, etc. My repositories encapsulate the data source. So a query can look for an object in the cache, failing that look in the db, failing that make a `REST` call to an external service to fetch the required information. This is fairly standard. Now the argument put forward by my colleagues is that abstracting the data source this way is dangerous because the developer using the repository will not be aware of the time required to execute the api and consequently not be able to calculate the execution time for any apis he writes above it. May be he would want to set up his component's behaviour differently if he knew that his call would result in a `REST` call. They are suggesting I move the `REST` call outside of the repository and maybe even the caching strategy along with it. I can see their point but the whole idea behind the repository pattern is precisely to hide this kind of information and not have each component deal with caching strategies and data access. My question is, is there a pattern or model which addresses this concern?

Answer (score 6):

> They are suggesting I move the REST call outside of the repository

Then you won't have a repository. The repository means we don't know persistence **details**, not that we don't know there is persistence. Every time we're using a repository, regardless of its implementation (from a in memory list to a REST call) we expect 'slowness' because it's common knowledge that persistence usually is the bottleneck.

Someone who will use a certain repository implementation (like REST based) will know it will deal with latency and transient errors. A service having just a `IRepository` dependency still knows it deals with persistence.

About caching strategies, you can have some service level (more generic) caching and repository level (persistence specific) caching. These probably should be implementation details.

> Now the argument put forward by my colleagues is that abstracting the data source this way is dangerous because the developer using the repository will not be aware of the time required to execute the api and consequently not be able to calculate the execution time for any apis he writes above it. May be he would want to set up his component's behaviour differently if he knew that his call would result in a REST call.

This is wasting time trying to complicate your life. The whole point of an abstraction is to hide the dirty details. What they suggest is basically: let's make the user aware of some implementation detail, so that the user can **couple** its code to that.

The point is, a developer should be aware of the api they're using. If a component is using an external service (db, web service), this should be known. Once you know there's data to be fetched, you know you'll have to wait for it.

If you go the DDD route then you have bounded contexts (BC). Making a model dependent on another BC is a **very bad idea** . Each BC should publish domain events and each interested BC should subscribe and keep their very own model based on those events. This means the queries will be 'local' but you'll still be hitting a db.

Comment: Upvoted. That's exactly what I think. I am still looking for some middle ground though. I would like to have some alternatives ready just to have a constructive conversation around the issue if for nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Repository pattern aim to reduce the coupling with persistence layer. In my opinion I wouldn't risk to make a repository so full of responsibility.

You could use an Anti Corruption Layer against changes in external service and a Proxy to hide the caching related issues.

Then in the application layer I will code the fallback strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends where you think the fetching/fallback strategy belongs, in the Service layer or in the Infrastructure layer (latter sounds more legit to me).

It could also be a mix of the two -- the Service is passed an ordered series of Repositories to use one after the other in case of failure. Construction of the series of Repos could be placed in the Infrastructure layer or somewhere else. Fallback logic in one place, fallback configuration in another.

As a side note, asynchrony seems like a good way to signal the users that something is *potentially* slow and would be blocking if you waited for it. Better than hiding everything behind a vanilla, inconspicuous Repository name and better than adding some big threatening "this could be slow" prefix to your type, IMO.